k8s: Statefulset with pvc templates and external pvc
I am trying to deploy my statefulset. The set contains 3 pvc templates and 1 externally managed PVC. The creation of the statefulset fails with the error shown below, I'm kind of lost what I am missing here.
Deployment method:

k8s version: 1.29.0
ArgoCD
Helm template

Deploying the statefulset returns the following error:

FailedCreate: create Pod myapp-0 in StatefulSet myapp failed error: Pod "myapp-0" is invalid: [spec.volumes[3].persistentVolumeClaim.claimName: Required value, spec.containers[1].volumeMounts[3].name: Not found: "external-pvc"]

Using argoCD I can see the my helm template deployed the desired manifest. I do see that the pvc has successfully deployed within the namespace (see manifest below):
Statefulset
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.16.0
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: myapp
    helm.sh/chart: myapp-0.1.6
  name: myapp
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
        app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
          image: 'lscr.io/linuxserver/myapp:latest'
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: myapp
          securityContext: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /config
              name: myapp-config
            - mountPath: /mount01
              name: myapp-01
            - mountPath: /mount02
              name: myapp-02
            - mountPath: /mount03
              name: external-pvc
      securityContext: {}
      volumes:
        - name: myapp-config
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: myapp-config
        - name: myapp-01
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimname: myapp-01
        - name: myapp-02
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimname: myapp-02
        - name: external-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimname: external-pvc
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: myapp-config
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        storageClassName: nfs-csi-applications
        volumeName: pv-myapp-config
    - metadata:
        name: myapp-01
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteMany
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Ti
        storageClassName: nfs-csi-applications
        volumeName: pv-myapp-01
    - metadata:
        name: myapp-02
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteMany
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 15Ti
        storageClassName: nfs-csi-applications
        volumeName: myapp-02

external-pvc
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: external-pvc
  namespace: mynamespace
  resourceVersion: '1314916'
  uid: 74972df6-ad14-49ab-afd9-dc8dffa0755a
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Ti
  storageClassName: nfs-csi-applications
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: pv-external-pvc
status:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 2Ti
  phase: Bound


I can see that you are defining volumeClaimTemplates and volumes with the same data. Have they been created manually?

Yes, the volumes have been created outside my helm chart and are managed in another way
